# How to alter the ownership of some tables inside a database from postgres to another user?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, psql, django-migrations

I have a database which contains significant number of tables. Some of the tables are owned by postgres user and not the one I created. I want to transfer the ownership of such tables to the one I created,because when doing django-migrations, you can only set one user and password for the psql connection and that user doesnt have access to the tables owned by the postgres user, thus the migrations are not completed.

So far, googling didn't help as they suggest either using **`ALTER`** or **`REASSIGN OWNED`**  to change the ownership of the database or the table. But the problem is that these cannot change the ownership of some of the tables as they are required to be owned by **`postgres`**. I can manually change the ownership by selecting each table one by one, but when trying to do altogether,I get an error saying

`"ERROR:  cannot reassign ownership of objects owned by role postgres because they are required by the database system"`.

Manually changing more than a hundred tables is not an option. Does anyone have any workaround idea for this issue?

Comment: First make sure that the original owner still hass access to them (so add permissions).

Comment: You can not change ownership of system objects, so y should change ownership only yours project tables.

Comment: You don't need to change ownership and as indicated cannot do so for system objects. But the owner can GRANT the necessary access to your user.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried with an [`anonymous code block`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpython-do.html)? This code block below selects all tables from the schema `public` that belongs to the user `postgres` and set the ownership to the user `user`:

```
DO $$
DECLARE row RECORD;
BEGIN
 FOR row IN SELECT * FROM pg_tables 
            WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tableowner = 'postgres' LOOP 
  EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE %I.%I OWNER TO user',row.schemaname,row.tablename);
 END LOOP;
END; 
$$;
```

Keep in mind that this operation will modify the ownership of **all tables** in your schema that belongs to the given user. Obviously you can further filter these tables by changing the `pg_tables` query in the loop. Take a look at:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tableowner = 'postgres';
```

Use it with care!

**EDIT**: To filter out a few tables from the selection above add a `NOT IN`, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_tables 
WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tableowner = 'postgres'
AND tablename NOT IN ('table1','table2','table3')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But I cannot change all the ownerships to the user. Some tables are required by postgres to be owned by postgres  user itself. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: @cmkishores how many tables need to remain with user `postgres`? if they're not many, we can manually exclude them from the selection. In case there are many of them, we need to find a pattern to filter them out automatically

Comment: The script would be more universal if the LOOP line is as follows:
`LOOP EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || row.schemaname || '.' || row.tablename || ' OWNER TO user';`

Comment: @sleepy012 thank you very much for the hint. I believe in January 2020 I was either not paying much attention or I just didn't know better :D I just edited my answer to accommodate the schema name. cheers