# How to drop role from database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried  to drop role admin using

```
reassign owned by admin to aus_owner;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE admin  IN SCHEMA public,firma1
   REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM admin;
drop role admin
```

but got error

```
 ERROR:  role "admin" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on
 it 
DETAIL:  privileges for schema public privileges for database aus

 privileges for schema firma1 privileges for table firma1.summav

 privileges for sequence firma1.summav_recnr_seq ... 
and 2406 other
 objects (see server log for list)
```

Using PostgreSQL 12.2

Comment: You need to change the owner of all objects belonging to admin see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59785733/how-to-alter-the-ownership-of-some-tables-inside-a-database-from-postgres-to-ano and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933327/best-way-to-change-the-owner-of-a-postgresql-database-and-their-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you ran `REASSIGN ALL`, it is probably enough to run

```
DROP OWNED BY admin;
```

to get rid of the privileges granted to the role. Then you should be able to drop it.

Read [this](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/drop-role-or-drop-user-postgresql/) for more background information.

Comment: Is it sure that DROP OWNED BY after REASSIGN OWNED BY will not delete any tables in database?

Comment: If the user does not own any tables (after `REASSIGN OWNED`), which tables would that be?